# Dynamically create check box fields in sencha touch 2 using json data and model

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

How to add check box Dynamically in form Panel. I need to store check box value and label in json data. If i enter the value in textbox and then click the add button to create check box dynamically from json label and  value.

This is my checkbox script:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        name : 'tomato',
        label: '{hardware}',
        value: '{tomato}',
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get access to your fieldset by either saving a reference to it when you create it:

```
var fieldset = Ext.create({
    items: [...]
});
```

..or by giving it an `id` and using that to reference it:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    id: 'myfieldset',
    items: [...]
}

...

var fieldset = Ext.getCmp('myfieldset');
```

Then you can dynamically insert a new checkbox using the [add](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-add) method on the fieldset:

```
var myData = {
    label: 'my label which i got via JSON',
    value: 1
};

fieldset.add({
    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
    name: 'tomato',
    label: myData.label,
    value: myData.value
});
```

Comment: thanks rdougan, it will work when i'm in view. but what i need is to create the checkbox when view is loading.